# My plea to re-open or migrate the question regarding contacts management

Tags: support, reopen-request

I asked this question:

[How do I manage contacts from multple accounts (twitter, facebook, gmail, etc,.)?](https://superuser.com/questions/596393/how-do-i-manage-contacts-from-multple-accounts-twitter-facebook-gmail-etc)

which was then close as 'Off-Topic':

> Questions on Super User are expected to relate to computer software or computer hardware within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about closed questions here.

The FAQ states (I've highlighted the related parts):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - **computer software**, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - **websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,**
> - **electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,**
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a shopping or product recommendation,

I understand that this question is probably a borderline topic due to it being about 'web services like Facebook, Twitter, etc,.' however this question is more about the integration of these services and my hardware/software interfaces like my desktop and outlook which are both on-topic as well as my tablets and phones which are not on-topic thus making this even more borderline.

I feel that this is a real problem that a lot of users face and ultimately what we're looking for is a solution (either practice or software) that will help to synchronize all of our contacts into one central place.  Is Super User a place to ask such a question?  If so, can we re-open?  If not, is there a place where this type of issue can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a [quick chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9515864#9515864) to have some questions of mine resolved, I think it's a valid question to ask on the site.

It's not necessarily a "software recommendation" question, as it could also be answered with a process or best practice that solves the problem at hand.

Given that there is already 1 reopen vote, I reopened the question.